# How to capture integers of varying length using regex

Tags: regex

If need to capture the following representative strings:

```
'About 1 results'
'About 5 results'
'About 10 results'
```

I just started touching regex today and currently have only gotten as far as `'[0-9] result'`. I feel like this should be pretty simple but I haven't been able to find a tutorial that is giving me what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[0-9]+` or `\d+`.  The plus makes it "one or more."